# APK Upload Failed because Certificate Change

Tags: java, android, google-play, apk, sha1

I have an application in Play Store. I had to change my PC and I configured everything again in new PC.

Now I generated a new APK and my SHA1 key is changed. Now when uploading a new apk to the play store it gives an error saying Certificate is different from the previous APK.

*What should I do?*

Comment: Have you created signed apk with the same keystore file?

Comment: I had to create another keystore as the previous one was tampered for some reason

Comment: In that case you will not be able to update the same application, if you want to update it you need the same keystore file using which you have uploaded the first version.

Comment: So do i have to create a new app in the play store?

Comment: Yes, without doubt, no other way

Answer (score 0):

You cannot push an update to an existing app in Google Play without signing the app with the certificate (SHA1) that was used for the first release.

Now your option is either to find the old signing certificate or you have to release your app as a new app in the play store listing (with a new package name).

Answer (score 0):

Before uploading the updated application, be sure that you have incremented the android:versionCode and android:versionName attributes in the element of the manifest file. Also, the package name must be the same and the .apk must be signed with the same private key. If the package name and signing certificate do not match those of the existing version, Market will consider it a new application and will not offer it to users as an update.